# Why does dpkg give me a "could not lock" error even after a reboot?

Tags: apt, dpkg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fixing “Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock”](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/fixing-could-not-get-lock-var-lib-dpkg-lock)

I get a dpkg is locked error even after a reboot??? i can't do any `apt-get` related commands

```
E: Could not lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock is not available - open (11:Resource is temporarily unavailable) 
E: The directory /var/lib/apt/lists/ not lock
E: Could not lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock is not available - open (11: Resource is temporarily unavailable) 
E: Can beheersmap (/var/lib/dpkg/) not lock. Is it in use by another process?
```

(dutch ubuntu above err code has been translated with [Google tranlsater](http://translate.google.nl/))

---

update 
I found the bug that caused this 
i added a [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~ed10vi86/+archive/ppa) that had Foxit Reader (PDF reader) installer in its repository.
the installer tries  to download from a link that is dead and it continues to
download it. i have no patient i `CTRL`-`Z`/`C`/`X`. it then paused the installer.
and then remaind locked.

do as @izx says

```
sudo rm -f /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
```

and then

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

then also

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Remove the ppa from software-sources and then run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get purge foxit-installer
```

and just in case you want to clean everything.

run these

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get check
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
```